# Can we call synchronized method of an object inside the constructor of the object in Java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, synchronized

I am new to Java. I am wondering if it is possible to call a synchronized method inside constructor. There is the example:

```
class a{
    int a1;

    public a(){
        a1 = 1;
        increment();
    }

    private synchronized void increment(){
        a1++;
    }
}
```

It is a toy example. I can just set the a1 to 2 at the constructor. I am just confused whether we can call `increment()` inside the constructor or not.

Comment: Hint: even in example code, use reasonable names. Class names go UpperCase, and a and a1 ... almost look the same, yet you use them for completely different things. Dont do that. use names that say what they are about!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that but that synchronization is meaningless because the synchronized method will lock the instance that is currently being created.  But which other thread could access it while that has not still be created and returned ? No one.
Constructors are indeed defacto thread safe as long as you follow good practices such as not passing `this` to other classes/objects inside the constructor body.
Your example could make more sense with a `synchronized static` method or `synchronized` on a `static` field.

Comment: Changing 'increment' to public makes the example more sensible.  Then, callers outside of the constructor have the advantage of synchronization, while the call from the constructor gets to reuse the code within 'increment' (and, for the most part, ignores the synchronization.)  The synchronization isn't *entirely* meaningless, since constructors can leak incompletely initialized objects to other threads, in which case a call to the synchronized method could occur while the new object was still being initialized.  (That's a rare but not non-existent problem.)

Comment: *"Constructors are indeed defacto thread safe."* ... this is usually true, except in the case of the constructor calling a non-final instance method with `this` as an argument.  In this case, it will be possible for a client of an API to observe an object in only a partially constructed state and to publish a reference to that object to other threads.

Comment: @scottb Agreed.  Passing this in a constructor is really something to avoid but that remains possible.  I added this point as simple and relevant.